# Tengo varios metodos creados, para insertar, eliminar y buscar datos de una lista en android Studio SQLite

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite, aplicación-movil

Tengo varios metodos creados, para insertar, eliminar y buscar datos de una lista y necesito ayuda en algo.
Quiero agregar un metodo para actualizar. en la vista principal de la nota tengo un Edit text y le siguen 3 botones; uno de buscar que al ingresar el titulo y darle buscar, muestre solo eso. el siguiente es de eliminar que al buscar y encontrar el titulo, si se presiona se elimina la nota y el tercero que es de actualizar y actualmente está sin uso. Lo que quiero es que al buscar y encontrar, me envíe a mi otra vista de "AddNote" pero que lleve consigo el dato(Titulo y nota) para poder editarlos y guardar cambios.el metodo update no sé como rellenarlo[image: metofos]

Comment: Voy a decirlo por si acaso, debes adjuntar tu código porque con una imagen se nos complica ayudar sin mencionar que en las normas se establece.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo hago es crear un método para actualizar y luego llamarlo a donde sea que lo necesite:

```
public void updateNotas(Notas notas) {
    this.openWriteableDB();
    db.update(ConstantsBD.TABLA_NOTAS, mapeoNotas(notas), "idNotas = " + ie.getIdNotas(), null);
    db.close();
}
```

El método `mapeoNotas`:

```
private ContentValues mapeoNotas(Notas notas) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(ConstantsBD.TITULO, notas.getTitulo());
    cv.put(ConstantsBD.NOTA_1, cam.getNota1());
    cv.put(ConstantsBD.NOTA_2, cam.getNota2());
    cv.put(ConstantsBD.NOTA_3, cam.getNota3());
    return cv;
}
```